# configuration(app.config or web.config) is not showing intellisense in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, web-config

I have created a project and due to some configuration needs I want to add some new key or new configuration elements. But I cant found there in the list.
[image: app config file image]

I have search a lot on internet but not found any proper solutions.
I have restarted the application, clear intellisense cache, reset the setting in visual studio and many more.

can anyone please help me out to get proper element list for web.conifg/app.conifg file.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is such a thing as intellisense for a config file. It's just XML that's parsed as runtime, so as long as it's valid XML, it should work.There are C# classes that help you parse it though.

Comment: no actually there is an intellisense that works for also web.config/app.config file in VS2012. That tells you that in which element what are the child element